# Get the symmetric difference from generic lists

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have 2 separate List and I need to compare the two and get everything *but* the intersection of the two lists.  How can I do this (C#)?

Comment: what do you mean by everything but the union?

Comment: Everything but the union is always nothing. Do you mean everything except the intersection?

Comment: Do you mean "but the intersection"?

Comment: Called the "symmetric difference" in set theory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory

Comment: @Daniel: I guess he means everything that is *not* in both lists.

Comment: Well - the union is going to contain everything in the two lists.  So assuming you're limiting the result to the values in the lists then the result is always the empty set.

Maybe you meant everything which isn't in the intersection of the lists?  (All values which are unique to one of the lists?)

Comment: Sorry :( yes I meant everything but the intersection

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) to get everything but the **intersection** of the two lists.

```
var differences = listA.Except(listB).Union(listB.Except(listA));
```

If you want to get everything but the **union**:

```
var allButUnion = new List<MyClass>();
```

(The union is everything in both lists - everything but the union is the empty set...)

Comment: Given that you're using the word "intersection" to describe what it means in English, doesn't it make sense to use it in the code as well? :)

Comment: Although, I seem to remember, when I had to do this for something, this was slightly more efficient than doing the total union and removing the intersection...

Comment: listA.Except(listB).Concat(listB.Except(listA)) 
could be more efficient

Comment: I started with your example. I then tried to write a Generic version and someone beat me to it:
https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Comment: There's also SymmetricExceptWith as pointed out in this blog entry:
http://www.skylark-software.com/2011/07/linq-and-set-notation.html

Answer (score 43):

If you mean the set of everything but the intersection (symmetric difference) you can try:

```
var set = new HashSet<Type>(list1);
set.SymmetricExceptWith(list2);
```

Comment: Excellent - that looks like the best way of doing it to me.

Comment: Very nice!  That's much cleaner than what I had.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean everything that's only in one list *or* the other? How about:

```
var allButIntersection = a.Union(b).Except(a.Intersect(b));
```

That's likely to be somewhat inefficient, but it fairly simply indicates what you mean (assuming I've interpreted you correctly, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
String[] one = new String[] { "Merry", "Metal", "Median", "Medium", "Malfunction", "Mean", "Measure", "Melt", "Merit", "Metaphysical", "Mental", "Menial", "Mend", "Find" };
            String[] two = new String[] { "Merry", "Metal", "Find", "Puncture", "Revise", "Clamp", "Menial" };

List<String> tmp = one.Except(two).ToList();
tmp.AddRange(two.Except(one));

String[] result = tmp.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generic Extension method. Rosetta Code uses Concat, and Djeefther Souza says it's more efficient.

```
public static class LINQSetExtensions
{
    // Made aware of the name for this from Swift
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683147/get-the-symmetric-difference-from-generic-lists
    // Generic implementation adapted from https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference
    public static IEnumerable<T> SymmetricDifference<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
    {
        // I've used Union in the past, but I suppose Concat works. 
        // No idea if they perform differently. 
        return first.Except(second).Concat(second.Except(first));
    }
}
```

I haven't actually benchmarked it. I think it would depend on how Union vs. Concat are implemented. In my dreamworld, .NET uses a different algorithm depending on data type or set size, though for IEnumerable it can't determine set size in advance.

Also, you can pretty much ignore my answer - Jon Skeet says that the HashSet method "Excellent - that looks like the best way of doing it to me."

Answer (score 1):

Use Except:

```
List<int> l1 = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
List<int> l2 = new List<int>(new[] { 2, 4 });
var l3 = l1.Except(l2);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just return the items in l1 that are not in l2? What if there are items in l2 not in l1?

Answer (score 1):

```
var theUnion = list1.Concat(list2);
var theIntersection = list1.Intersect(list2);
var theSymmetricDifference = theUnion.Except(theIntersection);
```