# List.Except returns only 1 item when there are several in the diff set

Tags: c#, list, except

In C# trying to do an Except between two lists of strings. There are some diff's, see the image below. At idx 2 and 19 note these are not the same. yet the List.Except method is only returning the last difference.

I call it like this: `var x = expList.Except(actList);`

Returns 1 item in the result: "site".

I expect 2 items: 4001, "site"

Anyone have any ideas as to what's going on here?

Thanks!

[image: Lists]

Comment: You're not showing all of the items (Note that the indices jump from 9->19)- "4001" must exist in the first list, as well.

Comment: What happened to indexes 10 to 18?

Comment: Take a look at `HashSet.SymmetricExceptWith()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alexei Levenkov mentioned, `Enumerable.Except` is not a "symmetric difference".

Consider:

```
new HashSet<string>(expList).SymmetricExceptWith(actList);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is not "symmetric difference" (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory), it is "set difference":

> the members of the first set that do not appear in the second set.

So if you first list is `{4002}` and second `{ 4001}` result of `Except` will not contain `4001`.

You may be looking for: [Get the symmetric difference from generic lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683147/get-the-symmetric-difference-from-generic-lists)

Comment: Ah, that is my mistake then. I thought it was a symmetrical difference. I suppose there isn't a Symm Diff method available?