# Show non matched values from two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio

How do I put into the collection of `ListBox` those items that doesn't have a pair from each array?

For example:

> first array = 100 500
>
> second array = 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800

Now, how do I show those non matched values `(200,400,600,700,800)` into `ListBox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ and `Except` method:

```
int[] result = secondArray.Except(firstArray).ToArray();
yourListBox.DataSource = result;
```

Also if you want to include values in `firstArray` that are not in `secondArray` go with the following query:

```
var result = firstArray.Except(secondArray).Union(secondArray.Except(firstArray)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet<int>` can easily do set operations like this. Go check out the [docs on that class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) and I'm sure you'll have an answer.   I believe you will be interested in the method `SymmetricExceptWith`

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the most efficient, but you can do

```
var firstArray = new int[2] {100,500};
var secondArray = new int[8] {100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800};

var x = secondArray.Except(firstArray);

foreach(var item in x)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less a duplicate of [Get the symmetric difference from generic lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683147/get-the-symmetric-difference-from-generic-lists).

> var differences = listA.Except(listB).Union(listB.Except(listA));