# EF: Select all that are not in another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am new to Entity Framework. In my case I got two tables: `Device` which stores all devices and `AssignedDevice` which stores all devices that are assigned at some time.

I written a select, that select all `Devices` which aren't assigned at the moment.

You can find the tables, the select, and my question below:

The model class for table `Device`:

```
public class Device 
{
        [Key]
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Brand")]
        [Required]
        public int BrandId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Model { get; set; }

        public Device()
        {
        }
}
```

Model class for table `AssignedDevice`:

```
public class AssignedDevice
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public Device Device { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Device")]
        public string DeviceId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime AssignedFrom { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime AssignedUntil { get; set; }

        public IdentityUser Assignee { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("Assignee")]
        [Required]
        public string AssigneeId { get; set; }

        public AssignedDevice()
        {
        }
}
```

And this is my "Select":

```
var query = _dbContext.Devices.Join(
                _dbContext.AssignedDevices,
                device => device.SerialNumber,
                assignedDevice => assignedDevice.Device.SerialNumber,
                (device, assignedDevice) => new 
                {
                    serialNumber = device.SerialNumber,
                    type = device.Type,
                    brand = device.Brand.BrandName, 
                    model = device.Model,
                    assignedFrom = assignedDevice.AssignedFrom,
                    assignedUntil = assignedDevice.AssignedUntil
                })
                .Where(assignedDevice => assignedDevice.assignedFrom > System.DateTime.Now || assignedDevice.assignedUntil < System.DateTime.Now)
                .ToList();
```

My question is:

How can I select all items which are in `Device` but not in `AssignedDevice`?

The data must be selected in the same select, which I have already written.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: You can use the `Except` method, something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42515973/2946329

Comment: The general approach (from SQL world) is to use `left outer join` (it can be emulated in LINQ) combined with `right == null` condition. However you cannot use the same select since `assignedDevice` will be `null`, so you'll need some modifications like making the result `assignedFrom` and `assignedUnitil` properties nullable. The EF (Core) way though is to define collection navigation property and use it instead of joins.  e.g. without projection the condition you are asking would be just something like `_dbContext.Devices.Where(device => !device.AssignedDevices.Any())`

Comment: Did you look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766856/select-records-that-does-not-exist-in-another-table-in-entity-framework 
`_dbContext.Devices`
        `.Where(ad => !_dbContext.AssignedDevices`
            `.Select(d => d.DeviceId)`
            `.Contains(ad.DeviceId)`
        `);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, you need to do left join instead of inner join. Here's a simple way to emulate left join in a LINQ query, using `.DefaultIfEmpty()`:

```
var query = 
    from d in _dbContext.Devices
    from ad in _dbContext.AssignedDevices.Where(ad => ad.DeviceId == d.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
    where ...
    select ...
```

If you want fields from your 'right' table in a query result, you'll have to take care of null references:

```
select new 
{
    AssignedFrom = ad != null ? ad.AssignedFrom : (DateTime?)null,
    ...
}
```

Basically what Ivan Stoev said in his comment.